# How to get method implementation and call with a type in Swift

Tags: swift, functional-programming

I'm trying to write functional programming with Swift. I want to compose functions which are already implemented by the standard library. Before composing, I need to get the method implementation for a type. How to do that?

```swift
let arr = [1, 2, 3]
let add10 = { x in x + 10}

// OOP way
arr.map(add10)    // [11, 12, 13]

// FP way
let fmap = Array.InstanceMethods.map // pseudo code to get `map` implementation
fmap(arr, add10)  // [11, 12, 13]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible approaches:

**1) declare a global function:**

```
    func functionalMap<Element, Output>(
        _ array: [Element],
        _ transform: (Element) -> Output) -> [Output] {
    
        array.map(transform)
    }
```

and then call it like this:

```
    let output = functionalMap(arr, add10)
```

**2. declare a struct:**

```
    struct FuctionalMap<Element, Output> {

        func callAsFunction(
            _ array: [Element],
            _ transform: (Element) -> Output) -> [Output] {
    
            array.map(transform)
        }
    }
```

and use it like this:

```
    let fmap = FuctionalMap<Int, Int>()
    let output = fmap(arr, add10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to `map` simply by `Array.map`, however the full function type needs to be specified when storing a closure. Due to the fact that `map` is a generic method over its return type, you can only store the partial application of map on a generic type.

```
struct GenericMapStorage<Value, Output> {
    let values: [Value]
    let transform: (Value) -> (Output)
    let map: ([Value]) -> ((Value) throws -> Output) throws -> [Output]
    
    init(values: [Value], transform: @escaping (Value) -> (Output)) {
        self.values = values
        self.transform = transform
        self.map = [Value].map(_:)
    }
}

let arr = [1,2,3]
let add10 = { $0 + 10 }

let parameters = GenericMapStorage(values: [1,2,3], transform: { $0 + 10 })
try parameters.map(parameters.values)(parameters.transform)
```